# What is @AutoAnnotation for? How could it be used?

Tags: java, android, annotations, dagger-2

In https://dagger.dev/multibindings.html, I read about @AutoAnnotation. It has a reference to https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/src/main/java/com/google/auto/value/AutoAnnotation.java.

It is also mentioned in 
https://github.com/google/auto/blob/57dfad360306619a820e6aae4a14a1aa67c29299/value/userguide/howto.md#annotation

I read about it, can't get to understand it.

I manage to access it from my Android code using

```
implementation 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2'
kapt 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2'
```

And also

```
android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true
```

But I don't understand how it could be used. Is there any good tutorial of using it?

Comment: Found a way to generate the AutoValue, and have it work. Example in 
 https://github.com/elye/issue_android_auto_value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AutoAnnotation](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/src/main/java/com/google/auto/value/AutoAnnotation.java#L24) automatically generates a class that implements an annotation interface in the same way the JDK does.

#### Dagger map keys

When using a Multibindings map through Dagger that uses a custom annotation as its key, Dagger will install the instance `T` or Provider `Provider<T>` into the returned map, using the annotation instance itself as the key. To make this clearer:

```java
@MapKey
@interface YourAnnotation {
  String foo();
}

@Provides @YourAnnotation(foo="bar") YourClass getYourClassForBar() { /* ... */ }

// Dagger will create a multibinding that would allow you to inject this:
@Inject Map<YourAnnotation, YourClass> map;
```

If the only thing that matters here is `foo`, you could also use `unwrapKeys` to make the map keyed by String instead of YourAnnotation, but let's assume you want this because you want YourAnnotation to have multiple values in the future. But where do the implementations of YourAnnotation come from, and how are you supposed to call `get` on the map?

#### Annotations at runtime

When you annotate a Java element (frequently a class, method, or field) Java will return a particular implementation of that class's annotation. From the [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html):

```java
@interface ClassPreamble {
   String author();
   String date();
   int currentRevision() default 1;
   String lastModified() default "N/A";
   String lastModifiedBy() default "N/A";
   // Note use of array
   String[] reviewers();
}

// [...]

@ClassPreamble (
   author = "John Doe",
   date = "3/17/2002",
   currentRevision = 6,
   lastModified = "4/12/2004",
   lastModifiedBy = "Jane Doe",
   // Note array notation
   reviewers = {"Alice", "Bob", "Cindy"}
)
public class Generation3List extends Generation2List {/* ... */}
```

In this usage, Generation3List has one Annotation of type ClassPreamble. If the annotation is retained at runtime (i.e. ClassPreamble itself is [annotated with `@Retention(RUNTIME)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#RUNTIME)), you can get to it via [`Generation3List.class.getAnnotations()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotations--) or [`Generation3List.class.getAnnotation(ClassPreamble.class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-). (There are also *declared* counterparts that handle superclass annotations differently.)

Once you get to an instance of ClassPreamble, you can use the methods like `author()` and `date()` to retrieve the data out of the class. However, ClassPreamble behaves as an interface, and the implementation of that annotation is internal to the VM. That makes it more difficult to create your own arbitrary instance of ClassPreamble at runtime.

#### Conforming annotation implementations

Because YourAnnotation and ClassPreamble are interfaces, you could just create an implementation. However, that implementation is unlikely to have matching implementations of `equals` and `hashCode` compared to the VM's implementation, because the implementation may vary between JREs and may also vary in Android. However, the implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` is actually very closely prescribed [in the docs for Annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html):

> The hash code of an annotation is the sum of the hash codes of its members (including those with default values), as defined below: The hash code of an annotation member is (127 times the hash code of the member-name as computed by String.hashCode()) XOR the hash code of the member-value, as defined below [...]
>
> Returns true if the specified object represents an annotation that is logically equivalent to this one. In other words, returns true if the specified object is an instance of the same annotation type as this instance, all of whose members are equal to the corresponding member of this annotation, as defined below [...]

It is possible to manually implement these rules, but it would be difficult to do so, and it would also impose a burden if the structure of YourAnnotation or ClassPreamble were to change. Though [there are reflective solutions to this problem](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/AnnotationUtils.html), AutoAnnotation generates the code for a conforming implementation automatically:

```java
public class YourAnnotations {
  @AutoAnnotation public static YourAnnotation yourAnnotation(String foo) {
    return new AutoAnnotation_YourAnnotations_yourAnnotation(foo);
  }
}

public class ClassPreambles {
  @AutoAnnotation public static ClassPreamble classPreamble(
      String author,
      String date,
      int currentRevision,
      String lastModified,
      String lastModifiedBy,
      String[] reviewers) {
    return new AutoAnnotation_ClassPreambles_classPreamble(
        author,
        date,
        currentRevision,
        lastModified,
        lastModifiedBy,
        reviewers);
  }
}
```

With AutoAnnotation's generated implementation, you can call `get` on the map that Dagger Multibindings generates (or provide test implementations you control) without having to deal with Annotation-specific `hashCode` XORs or `equals` rules. This is useful beyond Dagger and tests, but because Dagger uses annotation instances in its maps, it makes sense that you might need to use AutoAnnotation to create similar instances.

Comment: Thanks @jeff-bowman. To better understand this, I explore on AutoValue. However got stuck. Posted my question there. Hopes you could provide some insight. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58286591/autovalue-sample-error-cannot-find-symbol-class-autovalue-animal Thanks!

Comment: Great answer. In short, it's the AutoValue that generate Annotation key. Once I manage to get the AutoValue working, getting the AutoAnnotation working becomes natural. Thanks!!